# Opening multiple URL in one click

Tags: javascript, html

Have a look at my code, It opens only the first link and ignores the rest,

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://whitepages.co.nz/white-residential/T%20Vu/new-zealand/'); window.open('http://whitepages.co.nz/white-residential/T%20Vu/Auckland Central/'); window.open('http://whitepages.co.nz/white-residential/T%20H%20Vu/new-zealand/'); window.open('http://whitepages.co.nz/white-residential/T%20H%20Vu/Auckland Central/'); window.open('http://whitepages.co.nz/white-residential/H%20Vu/new-zealand/'); window.open('http://whitepages.co.nz/white-residential/H%20Vu/Auckland Central/'); window.open('http://whitepages.co.nz/white-residential/Vu/new-zealand/'); window.open('http://whitepages.co.nz/white-residential/Vu/Auckland Central/'); " class="btn btn-primary">Open All</a>
```

Comment: Opens all for me (Safari). http://jsfiddle.net/fSpSk/

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dH8YG/) with your code. My browser, quite understandably, throws a big fat popup warning and blocks all of them but two when I click the link. May I ask you the reason for going down that road instead of another, less annoying solution?

Comment: for me it opens 2 and stops right there.

Comment: what could be the less annoying solution ?

Comment: It's impossible for me to know, I don't know your intent. You could consider a different interface that doesn't involve flooding the user's screen with windows.

Comment: I just want to open the bunch of urls when the user clicks on one link..

Comment: oh yeah, I like this idea...

Comment: Added some dupe links, soon as a moderator takes a look. Your basic problem is that `window.open` is a tool of the spamming advertiser and is only allowed to be called once per user action.

Comment: I have tried with your code it is opening all url's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments and answers guys. It works like **thordarson** said. It was blocking the popups in my browser. When I enabled the popups it opened the `URL` in different windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
<a href="http://www.gmail.com" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com'); window.open('http://www.yahoo.com');">Link text</a>
```